# Application to create icons for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

Everytime I develop iOS application on Xcode, I spend a long time to generate all icons (76pt, 40pt, 29pt, 60pt, @1x, @2x, @3x).

Is there an application out there that would create all these formats automatically based on a source image ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can create an action to Photoshop. Easy thing many tutorials out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org) installed with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), and a large icon (say, 1024x1024) named icon.png, you can run the following shell script in Terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
for size in {76,40,29,60}; do for scale in {1,2,3}; do
    if [[ $scale == 1 ]]; then
        filename="icon_${size}.png"
    else
        filename="icon_${size}@${scale}x.png"
    fi
    gm convert "icon.png" -resize "$(( $scale * $size ))x$(( $scale * $size ))" "$filename"
done; done
```

This will spit out a number of resized images, correctly named.

Adjust as needed for the sizes and the scales, or to provide input filename (`icon.png` is hard-coded) as an argument to the script (using `$1` instead).

Answer (score -1):

Just found one online tool handy:

https://makeappicon.com/

This tool will generate all icon sizes required by Xcode for a complete Asset Catalog. It supports generating Android icons as well.

Another solution is to write a script to generate the icons, using `python/PILLOW` to resize.